# C++. Loading csv files to 2D vectors

Tags: c++, string, csv, vector, loading

I've loaded a CSV file (`platforms.csv`) into a 2D vector with seemingly no problem, but when I manipulate the string from `[0][0]` it behaves weird. Can someone please help me figure out what's wrong?

My goal is to simply load a CSV file into a 2D vector and be able to manipulate the strings as I would any other string. This initial CSV file contains the names of other CSV files (without the `.csv` extension), so I eventually want to add `.csv` to all of the strings from `platforms.csv` that are loaded into `platformsCSV`.

The contents of `platforms.csv` are simply:

```
PrestaShop
osCommerce
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
PrestaShop
osCommerce

.csvtaShop
osCommerce.csv
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void readCSV(string &readFileName, vector< vector<string> > &output, int &colCount, int &rowCount)
{
    fstream file(readFileName, ios::in);

    if(!file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File not found!\nEnter correct file name: ";
        cin >> readFileName;
    }

    colCount = 0, rowCount = 0;
    string csvLine;
    while( getline(file, csvLine) )
    {
        istringstream csvStream(csvLine);
        vector<string> csvColumn;
        string csvElement;
        while( getline(csvStream, csvElement, ',') )
        {
            csvColumn.push_back(csvElement);
            colCount++;
        }
        output.push_back(csvColumn);
        rowCount++;
    }
    colCount=colCount/rowCount;
    file.close();
}

void writeCSV(string &writeFileName, vector< vector<string> > &csvData, int &colCount, int &rowCount)
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open (writeFileName);
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    while(y<rowCount) {
        x=0;
        while (x<colCount-1) {
            myfile << csvData[y][x] << ",";
            x++;
        }
        myfile << csvData[y][x] << "\n";
        y++;
    }
    myfile.close();
}



int main()
{
    int colCount, rowCount;

    string platformsFile = "platforms.csv";
    vector< vector<string> > platformsCSV;

    readCSV(platformsFile, platformsCSV, colCount, rowCount);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n" << platformsCSV[0][0];
    cout << "\n" << platformsCSV[1][0];

    string x = platformsCSV[0][0] + ".csv";
    string y = platformsCSV[1][0] + ".csv";
    cout << "\n";
    // What's wrong here???
    cout << "\n" << x;
    cout << "\n" << y;
    cout << "\n";    

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What do you see when you run it in the debugger?

Comment: There's no bug, it's runs fine. Just getting an incorrect output (.csvtaShop instead of the PrestaShop.csv

Comment: You're missing the point. The debugger lets you see at exactly which point what your program does diverges from what you think it does; that is unlikely to be at the end where you print the results.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I'm such a beginner I don't even know how to debug. It's very much a patchwork project :/

Comment: @StevenTalafous you should start with that. It's extremely useful and relatively easy thing to learn in decent IDE.

Comment: If, in the code you posted, I replace `fstream file(readFileName, ios::in);` with `fstream file(readFileName.c_str(), ios::in);` and `myfile.open (writeFileName);` with `myfile.open (writeFileName.c_str());` it works fine.  Are you sure the code you posted is your actual code?

Comment: @Jerry Overloads accepting `std::string` for the file names were added in C++11.

Comment: @AlanStokes  I obviously wasn't using the C++11 flag...  I didn't realize it was necessary.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah looked like that would help, tried it, and still have the same output

Answer (score 2):

Isn't a problem of C++ code. It's a problem of CSV end-of-lines.

If I'm not wrong, obviously.

I've reproduced your problem, getting

```
.csvtaShop
.csvmmerce
```

in a linux platform, where lines in text files ends with LF (0x0a), using a CSV file with dos line endings (CR+LF, 0x0d+0x0a).

`getline()` load in `csvElement` "Prestashop\x0d" and "osCommerce\x0d", loading the '\x0d' chars.

When I print `platformsCSV[0][0]` and `platformsCSV[1][0]`, I get

```
PrestaShop
osCommerce
```

because the '\x0d' char is invisible.

My `x` and `y` becomes "PrestaShop\x0d.csv" and "osCommerce\x0d.csv".

Printing `x`, `cout` write "PrestaShop", then the "\x0d" char -- that is: go to left of the line -- and then the ".cvs" part, that overwrite "Pres".

Very similar with my `y`.

If you get

```
.csvtaShop
osCommerce.csv
```

I suppose you're working in a Linux (or Unix) platform and that your CSV file ends with CR+LF at the end of the first line but that is without end of line at the end of the second line.

To verify if my hypothesis is correct, you can add

```
for ( unsigned i = 0 ; i < x.size() ; ++i )
   std::cout << '[' << int(x[i]) << ']';
std::cout << '\n';
```

at the end of your `main()`

I get

```
[80][114][101][115][116][97][83][104][111][112][13][46][99][115][118]
```

Where the '\x0d' is the `[13]`

Solution (if my hypothesis is correct): trasform your CSV file in a unix text file.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.